# Remove the node in Binary Search Tree

Tags: java, data-structures, binary-search-tree

How can I remove all `isRemoved=true;` data in Binary Search Tree in one method?
Or two it doesn't matter.
There is a remove method already and it marks the node that is coming from method `isRemoved=true`.
So,constructor has four specilization they are `Type data`,`left`,`right`,`isRemoved`.
The method can work recursively or not doesn't matter.

---

My idea is traversing all of the nodes when I found the removed go and delete method and delete it then turn back and keep going look at the nodes. I couldn't implement the idea because BST is complicated. Can you guys give me some clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you will need to decide how you are going to traverse your tree (inorder, preorder, postorder).

Then you will handle three separate cases for a node to be deleted; when the node is a leaf, when the node has one child, and when there are both a left and a right child.

- If the node is a leaf, you can remove it.
- If the node has a child, you can set the node's child to be the parent node's child, then remove the node.
- If the node has two children, you can go to the subtree of the left child and replace the node with the rightmost child of the left subtree. Since the rightmost node in the subtree is a leaf, you can replace without rebalancing the tree.

Traverse the tree while removing the isRemoved=true nodes using one of the methods above until you reach the last node in the traversal.